Why AUC for trainset prediction such high in a random forest model?
I tried to learn how to tune a random forest model by grid search in caret. And the AUC for the trainset prediction was pretty high (AUC=1). Was the model overfitting? Or did I do something wrong with the trainset prediction?
Here is the code I used as below:
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar) # I used the Sonar dataset for training

# I just tried to learn how to tune the rf model, so I didn't split it into trainset and testset.
x<-Sonar[,1:60]
y<-Sonar[,61]

library(caret)

set.seed(1234)
cv_folds <- createFolds(y, k = 10, returnTrain = TRUE)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                     number = 10,
                     search = 'grid',
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     savePredictions = TRUE,
                     index = cv_folds,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary) 
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(1:10))
ntrees <- c(500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500)    
nodesize <- c(1,3,5,7,10)

params <- expand.grid(ntrees = ntrees,
                      nodesize = nodesize)

store_maxnode <- vector("list", nrow(params))
for(i in 1:nrow(params)){
  nodesize <- params[i,2]
  ntree <- params[i,1]
  set.seed(123)
  rf_model <- train(Class~.,
                    data = Sonar,
                    method = "rf",
                    importance=TRUE,
                    metric = "ROC",
                    tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                    trControl = ctrl,
                    ntree = ntree,
                    nodesize = nodesize)
  store_maxnode[[i]] <- rf_model
}
names(store_maxnode) <- paste("ntrees:", params$ntrees,
                              "nodesize:", params$nodesize)

tune_result<-lapply(store_maxnode, function(x) x$results[x$results$ROC == max(x$results$ROC),])
tune_result #ROC reached 0.9530808 at ntrees=1000, and nodesize=1

#save the best model 
best_model<-store_maxnode$`ntrees: 1000 nodesize: 1`

#predict on trainset
rf_pred<-predict(best_model,newdata=x,type="prob")
df<-data.frame(pred=rf_pred$R,origin=ifelse(Sonar$Class=="R",1,0))
pred_obj <- ROCR::prediction(df[["pred"]],df[["origin"]])
auc <- ROCR::performance(pred_obj, measure = "auc")
auc@y.values 



Use a training and test set
You are evaluating the model's accuracy on the training data. Your data has about 200 rows and 60 columns. With a random forest of 1000 trees, assuming you do not have identical rows with different outcomes, you're very likely to achieve perfect accuracy on the training data. This is overfitting. If you split into training and test sets, you'll see a big different between performance on the training set and test set. Here is how to do this:
1. Train test split
# Split into train and test set
set.seed(123)
train_idx <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
sonar_train <- Sonar[train_idx, ] # 157 rows
sonar_test <- Sonar[-train_idx, ] # 51 rows

# Apply cross-validation to training set y
cv_folds <- createFolds(sonar_train$Class, k = 10, returnTrain = TRUE)

# Set train control
ctrl <- trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    number = 10,
    search = "grid",
    classProbs = TRUE,
    savePredictions = TRUE,
    index = cv_folds,
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
)
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(1:10))

2. Train model
Then train the model only on your training set using your grid of parameters:
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(1:10))
ntrees <- c(500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500)
nodesize <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 10)

params <- expand.grid(
    ntrees = ntrees,
    nodesize = nodesize
)

store_maxnode <- vector("list", nrow(params))
for (i in 1:nrow(params)) {
    nodesize <- params[i, 2]
    ntree <- params[i, 1]
    set.seed(123)
    rf_model <- train(
        Class ~ .,
        data = sonar_train,
        method = "rf",
        importance = TRUE,
        metric = "ROC",
        tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
        trControl = ctrl,
        ntree = ntree,
        nodesize = nodesize
    )
    store_maxnode[[i]] <- rf_model
}

3. Plot the respective ROC curves
We can immediately see the huge difference between the training and test sets. The model is a perfect classifier on the data it is trained on, which is not surprising, given the large number of parameters relative to the number of rows. However, it doesn't perform nearly so well on the test set.
preds_list_test <- lapply(store_maxnode, \(rf_model) {
    ifelse(
        predict(rf_model, newdata = sonar_test) == "R", 1, 0
    )
})
preds_list_train <- lapply(store_maxnode, \(rf_model) {
    ifelse(
        predict(rf_model, newdata = sonar_train) == "R", 1, 0
    )
})

labels_list_test <- lapply(seq_along(store_maxnode), \(.) ifelse(sonar_test$Class == "R", 1, 0))
labels_list_train <- lapply(seq_along(store_maxnode), \(.) ifelse(sonar_train$Class == "R", 1, 0))

pred_test <- ROCR::prediction(preds_list_test, labels_list_test)
pred_train <- ROCR::prediction(preds_list_train, labels_list_train)

perf_test <- ROCR::performance(pred_test, "tpr", "fpr")
perf_train  <- ROCR::performance(pred_train, "tpr", "fpr")

par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(perf_train,
    colorize = TRUE,
    lwd = 2,
    main = "ROC curves for train"
)
plot(perf_test,
    colorize = TRUE,
    lwd = 2,
    main = "ROC curves for test"
)


There is one "curve" (it's a line in this case) for each model (i.e. each row of params). The area under the curve is indeed always 1 on the training data, for all models. It looks not bad in some of the train models, but it's certainly nowhere near perfect.
4. Extract best performing model
The way you were evaluating your model was also a bit error-prone. For an ROC curve, you want to predict the classes rather the probabilities (which you can't compare to the test set as it doesn't have probabilities):
# Find the best performing model
tune_result <- Map(
    \(x, y, z) cbind(x$results, n_trees = y, nodesize = z),
    store_maxnode, params$ntrees, params$nodesize
) |> do.call(rbind, args = _)

# Look at best performing model parameters
tune_result[which.max(tune_result$ROC), ]
#   mtry       ROC      Sens      Spec      ROCSD     SensSD    SpecSD n_trees nodesize
# 1    2 0.9475322 0.9416667 0.7696429 0.03163401 0.06169752 0.1173842    1000        1

# save the best model
best_model <- store_maxnode[[which.max(tune_result$ROC)]]

# Predict on test set
rf_pred <- predict(best_model, newdata = sonar_test)
# ROCR doesn't seem to like factors - this is OK as levels are the same order
pred_obj <- ROCR::prediction(
    as.numeric(rf_pred),
    as.numeric(sonar_test$Class)
)

auc <- ROCR::performance(pred_obj, measure = "auc")
auc@y.values
# [1] 0.8171296

We can see that actually your best performing model with 1000 trees has an AUC of around 0.82, which is decent, but it is not a perfect classifier.

Thanks for your time. I understand that performance on testing set will provide us a better evaluation on the model. But I am more stuck on the trainset prediction (though it is meaningless for real model performance evaluation). So I post a new question to summarize the problems I have: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78487432/6918651

Also I am not sure the way you calculated AUC was correct. We do need probabilities returned from the predict() by setting type="prob". Basically, ROC curve was constructed with different sets of FPR and TPR with the change of threshold. For example, if one predicted probability was 0.456, then the predicted class will be 0 when threshold is 0.5, but will be 1 when threshold is 0.4. However, if you use predicted class, you turn 0.456 into 0 already, and then the predicted class will be 0 whatever the threshold is. The ROC curve will be different based on the value you use as well as AUC.
